# Not able to add int value to timestamp

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am writing a query in AWS Glue job using SQL. I want to add seconds to the timestamp field 1 and want to return the value in timestamp. I am writing query using spark.sql.

Eg. `timestamp field 1- 2021-08-05 04:00:00`, `field 2- 30(this value is int)` `Output - 2021-08-05 04:00:30`

I am unable to do that and i couldn't find the correct syntax anywhere. This is what I am using it doesn't seem to work.

`date_add(m.field1,m.field2)`

The error I am getting is the input mismatch error as `m.field1` is Int and `m.field2` is timestamp . Thanks

`spark.sql(select abc.a, abc.b, abc.c ,date_add(abc.field1,abc.field2) AS d from abc)`

Here,`abc.field1 -int` and `abc.field2 - timestamp`.

Error message:

`` An error occurred while calling o68.sql. : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'date_add(m.`watched_time`, m.`server_time`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires date type, however, 'm.`watched_time`' is of decimal(20,0) type. argument 2 requires int type, however, 'm.`server_time`' is of timestamp type.; ``

Comment: Can you clarify which field is the timestamp and which field is the int? In your first example you have `field1` as timestamp and then you go on to say that `m.field1` is int. Also please post the exact text of the error message.

Comment: Also, this looks like you're working in Scala. If so, can you add the appropriate tag?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question.  The first argument is int and the second one is timestamp. Hope this makes things clear. Thanks.

Comment: Two things: `date_add` expects the date as the first argument, but you're passing the  number as the first argument. At the very least you need to reorder your arguments to `date_add` and pass `m.server_time` first, but I'm not sure that you have the types right. `m.watched_time` is  a decimal and `date_add` expects int. Second, the [documentation for date_add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_add) indicates that it adds days to the date, and you say you want to add seconds. `date_add` doesn't sound like it will do that for you.

Comment: Can we use any other alternative instead of `date_add`

Answer (score 0):

Spark 3.0 exposed the [`make_interval` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#make_interval) that you can use to add an arbitrary interval to a timestamp. Here's a quick example that shows adding the value of an integer column as seconds on a timestamp.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Calendar
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object ScalaDateTransform {
    
    def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
        val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
        val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
        val sparkSession: SparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession
        import sparkSession.implicits._
       

        val df = Seq(
          (30, Timestamp.valueOf("2021-08-05 04:00:00")),
          (45, Timestamp.valueOf("2020-11-30 12:40:32")),
          (60, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-12-29 09:54:00")),
          (90, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-09 10:12:43"))
        ).toDF("watched_time","server_time")
       
        val df2 = df.withColumn("plus_watched_time", 
                        expr("server_time + make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, watched_time)"))
        
        df2.printSchema()
        df2.show()
    }

}
```